# What Content-Type should a 204 No Response use?

Tags: http, rest

When building a RESTful HTTP service, and a Response is given with a 204 No Content (e.g. after the Consumer issues a DELETE Request), what Content-Type should the Response include?

Should it be omitted?
Is there a preferred Content-Type?
Should it be the same Content-Type of a GET Request to the same Resource?
Does it not matter whatsoever?

Comment: Related to, or possible duplicate of: [Should content-type header be present when the message body is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784398/should-content-type-header-be-present-when-the-message-body-is-empty)

Comment: Yes, the other question duplicated my question 15 months after it was asked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have `Content-Type` when you have content and even then it's optional:

> Any HTTP/1.1 message **containing an entity-body SHOULD** include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body.

(from [RFC2616, §7.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1), please note the use of SHOULD).

Since there is no content, then there is no reason to specify a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I believe https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-7.2.1 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Well, there's a little more to the story though, and it involves when the real-world (browsers) meet the theoretical world (specifications). Seems Firefox (ver 38 as I write this) has a bug where the browser attempts to parse the content as xml if there's no content-type header, EVEN WHEN the response code is 204 (no content). See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521301

So, while a content type header doesn't make much sense when there's no content (and there MUST NOT be content on a 204) it seems to make sense to return some header anyway. And I don't see where that would be a violation of the spec.

Comment: That bug seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Though I do note that they say "The XHR's responseXML will be null and a parsing failure will simply be logged to the web console instead." so we'd still be creating console spew... I'd stick w/still returning the Content-Type header.

Comment: The error doesn't seems to occur when browser get the response, but when browser *try to get the XML* with [`responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML). If that's the case, I wonder whether it's even a bug.