# Lumen does send 204 response

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I have created the following function into the main Controller.

```
public function noContent() : JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json([], Response:HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

When deleting some data, I am returning the above function but I get a message that "Could not get any response".

I also have tried to pass a message (even if this is not recommended for a 204) in the array but still, I receive the same error. I am using the same function to return 200 or 404 messages and there worked as expected.

Is there another solution to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps you are sending a `Content-Type` header? [Some clients behave badly with that combination.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21029351/2908724)

Comment: I was sending a content-type header, I have removed it but still get the same result.

Comment: you can try `return response(null, Response:HTTP_NO_CONTENT);` instead. And if your intent is to not return any content in the response, remove the return type from the method signature

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You should do:

```
return response('', 204);
```