# "www.googleapis.com" response recently changed

Tags: rest, httpresponse, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Request with the following URL.
*Replace "domain.com" with your gsuite domain.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06336@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06336@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=MEMBER
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06334@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06334@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=MEMBER
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06330@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f309c3412@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER
```

This event is more likely to occur when the owner and members of a group without members are alternately acquired.
Some REST clients try to parse the body.
Because of that, it becomes an error and is troubled.

The usual Request / Response

```
GET /admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06336@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer beara

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 2
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-location: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06336@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 02:26:23 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: GSE
Etag: "xW2YlxjdVEsAJNu_Hp5Dnespo8s/HMFwD2wLX237BRmKZQUJYB5ZE7U"
Cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 02:26:23 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
-content-encoding: gzip

{}
```

Unexpected response

```
GET /admin/directory/v1/groups/ac-c.ou_n-t_16f30a06334@domain.com/members?fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer beara
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-length: 0
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
Etag: "MiyCzqTTHAT4o-bfHCteagJNIb0h9mrrv2lNyYYkGw0/HMFwD2wLX237BRmKZQUJYB5ZE7U" 
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2019 07:31:51 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Reference information：
[What Content-Type should a 204 No Response use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029351/what-content-type-should-a-204-no-response-use)

Comment: This is interesting. I cannot reproduce it. Can you try to gather more information and patterns on when and how often it occurs? Does it occur only for certain groups? Does it occur if you do not specify the pageToken? Or leave out other parameters?

Comment: [I'm trying on this site.](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) 
The condition is a group that has no members.
scope :https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
The parameters are reproduced by specifying the following:
fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,nextPageToken&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER

Thank you @ziganotschka

Comment: What about skipping `nextPageToken`? If a group has no members, probably you will not have mor than one page.

Comment: This phenomenon occurs with a probability of about 40%.

The same phenomenon occurs even if the following nextPageToken is skipped.
fields=members/type,members/email,members/role&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER 

I found a solution that does not cause 204 by adding a parameter with a useless etag such as: fields=members/type,members/email,members/role,etag&maxResults=200&prettyPrint=false&roles=OWNER 

Thank you for your reply.  @ziganotschka